# Using zlib in Visual C++ project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, zlib

I've been struggling to compile my Visual C++ 2010 project with dependency of Zlib. I've got source code that worked on Linux and Mac OS X. Here's, where I have linker errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflate@8 referenced in function...
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateInit2_@16 referenced in function...
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate@8 referenced in function...
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateInit2_@32 referenced in function...
```

I've been finding solution for few days now, trying compiling Zlib different ways, but it is clear that I've missed something. Very similar question has been answered here, but not clearly enough for amateur like me. I would need step-by-step guide how to get it to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried going to the Zlib web site and downloading their latest files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have static libraries after building the Zlib, point them in your project at this location.Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies. Give the absolute path.

Comment: I did it via VC++ Include and Library Directories, isn't it the same?

Comment: I don't know 2010. You right click on the project and select properties, it will take you the property pages. I see your includes are right. The problem is with library. Assume if your static libs are in `C:/repo/libs/`, in the additional dependencies you have to give `c:/repo/libs/abc.lib;c:/repo/libs/def.lib` and so forth. Or else, you can give the `c:/repo/libs/` path in the `linker>General>additional Linker directories`. After that you need to specify `abc.lib;def.lib` in the `Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies`. I remember both of them works. Give it a try.