# How to unzip a zipped file(.zip) using C++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unzip, compression

I'm working on a C++ project which needs a **unzip** feature in it.

I've searched on the internet and found out **zlib** may be useful, but it turns out zlib just provides for C language version, and C++ version is just for Linux.

I've also found that MSDN has their own API : **Decompress** & **Compress** function, but after I tried the Decompress function to decompress a zipped file, I found that the MSDN "Decompress" function is only useful for the file which is compressed by their own MSDN "Compress" function.

In other words, if I have a `.zip` file, I'm not able to use the MSDN API to decompress it.

Hope anyone has any idea to help me, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: C can be called from C++ (and most other languages) just fine.

Comment: If you want to use the API, there is [ZipFile Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) supported by .NET Framework 4.5 and higher.

Comment: to Angew: I know, but since I put the downloaded zlib in my project and compile, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: To  kunif : How do I use the .NET Framework  API in my C++ project?

Comment: And as a way of @Angew, this [Using zlib in Visual C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616860/using-zlib-in-visual-c-project) will be helpful.

Comment: To call .NET from C++, specify an option [to use common language runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation) in project properties. From C++, you can call it by writing namespace::class::method().

Comment: The above was too rough. Detailed articles are below.  [Using C# from native C++ with the help of C++/CLI (fixed and enhanced)](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/),  [Mixing .NET and native code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35041/mixing-net-and-native-code),  [Consuming C# Library in native C or C++ using C++/Cli](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5),  [Using .NET Classes/Modules from Native C++](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42319/using-net-classes-modules-from-native-c)

Comment: Thanks for all your response, it really helps me a lot !!! My project finally can compile well. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try libzip? Here is an example. You should also find some wrapers from Github, such as [libzippp](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp).

```
bool unzip(const std::wstring &zipPath, const std::wstring &desPath)
{
    int err;
    struct zip *hZip = zip_open_w(zipPath.c_str(), 0, &err);
    if (hZip)
    {
        size_t totalIndex = zip_get_num_entries(hZip, 0);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < totalIndex; i++)
        {
            struct zip_stat st;
            zip_stat_init(&st);
            zip_stat_index(hZip, i, 0, &st);

            struct zip_file *zf = zip_fopen_index(hZip, i, 0);
            if (!zf)
            {
                zip_close(hZip);
                return false;
            }

            std::vector<char> buffer;
            buffer.resize(st.size);
            zip_fread(zf, buffer.data(), st.size);
            zip_fclose(zf);

            // your code here: write buffer to file
            // desPath
            // st.name: the file name

        }
        zip_close(hZip);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I didn't tried this method, but thanks for your response instead!